# can't get data from mongodb using perl (get undefined value)

Tags: mongodb, perl

I am trying to get data from mongodb using perl, but I get undefined value for variable `$people`

```
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(host => 
'mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',port=>27017, username => 'xxxx', 
password => 'xxxx');
my $db = $client->get_database("xxx");
my $collection = $db->get_collection("xxx");
my $people = $collection->find_one({"transactionid" => $id});
while (my $p = $people->next) {
    print Dumper $p;
}
```

and I want to get this data :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c453500e2fb4adc98e9fa84"),
    "transactionid" : NumberLong(45282),
    "transactionbillerid" : NumberLong(43137),
    "requesttime" : ISODate("2019-01-21T02:57:04.923Z"),
    "requestmessage" : "xxxxxxxx",
    "responsetime" : ISODate("2019-01-21T02:57:05.236Z"),
    "responsemessage" : "xxx"
}
```

any suggestions, is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Most likely, `$id` does not have the value you think it has, or there is no element in your collection with the `transactionid` you're looking for,

Comment: I get $id value from param..
`my $id = $query->param('trx_id');` and there is element in my collection with `transactionid` I'm looking for :D

Comment: Does the query work with `$id` set to a hardcoded value? Try `my $id = '1234';` (or whatever the value is) to see if it works. Also, `->find_one` does not return an iterator but the document itself.

Comment: still the same and I just changed my code... XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the value returned by `find_one()`. There's a big clue in the name, but `find_one()` returns a single record, not an iterator.

Obviously, I don't have access to your data, so I can't confirm this, but I expect you'll get what you want by running this code:

```
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(
  host     => 'mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  port     => 27017,
  username => 'xxxx', 
  password => 'xxxx',
);

my $db = $client->get_database("xxx");
my $collection = $db->get_collection("xxx");

my $person = $collection->find_one({"transactionid" => $id});
print Dumper $person;
```

Comment: I got this response `$VAR1 = undef;` .-.
actually I use this for cgi-perl..

Comment: @YudistiraSugandi check your query. In the code you provided there's no a value assignment to `$id`.. is it a typo error? BTW the answer of @davecross is correct.

Comment: I got it from `my $id = $query->param('trx_id');` , and I don't know why I got undef value...

Comment: and I got new error like this `MongoDB::DecodingError: Invalid UTF-8 detected while decoding BSON at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24/MongoDB/BSON.pm`

Comment: `$query->param` smells of a query string parameter got using the CGI module.
Well.. I guess the problem is in the input data at HTTP layer, so focus your debug on that direction. Check the data received by your web request handler, and why the `trx_id` parameter is empty.

Comment: @YudistiraSugandi this is not a real time support chat. Please, detail you problem with a complete example and , if needed, open a new post for it for avoiding confusion.

Comment: actually, this answer is correct, I got invalid utf8 because there are invalid utf8 in my mongodb data... :D